# JSON serialisers/deserialisers Play Framework

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.0

I want create JSON serialisers/deserialisers for a Play Framework project, this is my code:

```
    object ClientConnection {

      /**
       * Events to/from the client side
       */
      sealed trait ClientEvent

      case class UserPing() extends ClientEvent

      /**
       * Event sent from the client when they have moved
       */
      case class UserMoved(position: Point[LatLng]) extends ClientEvent

    /**
       * Formats WebSocket frames to be ClientEvents.
       */
      implicit def clientEventFrameFormatter: FrameFormatter[ClientEvent] = FrameFormatter.jsonFrame.transform(
        clientEvent => Json.toJson(clientEvent),
        json => Json.fromJson[ClientEvent](json).fold(
          invalid => throw new RuntimeException("Bad client event on WebSocket: " + invalid),
          valid => valid
        )
      )

/**
   * JSON serialisers/deserialisers for the above messages
   */
  implicit def clientEventFormat: Format[ClientEvent] = Format(
    (__ \ "event").read[String].flatMap {
      case "user-moved" => UserMoved.userMovedFormat.map(identity)
      case "user-ping" => UserPing.userPingFormat.map(identity)
      case other => Reads(_ => JsError("Unknown client event: " + other))
    },
    Writes {
      case um: UserMoved => UserMoved.userMovedFormat.writes(um)
      case pi: UserPing => UserPing.userPingFormat.writes(pi)
    }
  )

  object UserMoved {
    implicit def userMovedFormat: Format[UserMoved] = (
      (__ \ "event").format[String] and
          (__ \ "position").format[Point[LatLng]]
      ).apply({
      case ("user-moved", position) => UserMoved(position)
    }, (userMoved: UserMoved) => ("user-moved", userMoved.position))
  }
```

Now my question is, how I can map the Ping request, that have a JSON format with the only 1 key like this:

```
{ "event" : "user-ping"}
```

I have tried to do this:

```
object UserPing {
    implicit def userPingFormat: Format[UserPing] = (
      (__ \ "event").format[String]
      ).apply({
      case ("user-ping") => UserPing()
    }, (userPing: UserPing) => ("user-ping"))
  }
```

but give me an error compiling, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and write manually your own Writes

```
implicit val userPing Writes: Writes[UserPing] = new Writes[UserPing] {
   def writes(a: UserPing): JsValue = Json.obj("event" -> "user-ping")
}
```

Is this what you need?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i have changed my Formatter, and i have open a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34334733/play-framework-frameformatter-with-array-of-object if you can help me:) thanks